# How can I have two calendars in the `DatePicker` component of MUI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui, mui-x

the `<DateRangePicker/>` component from MUI, accept a props named `calendars` that accept number of calendars that showing inside component popup, like this:

like it that had "3" value as its `calendars` props:

[image]

but `DatePicker` component hasn't that and cant handle this.

i want two use `DatePicker` component, for single select and not range select, but with two calendar.

something like this just for example!:
`<DatePicker calendars={2} />`

Answer (score 1):

The `DatePicker` component is built to pick one, and one date only, hence why it will only ever contain one calendar.

If you want to select 2 dates, either use 2 distinct `DatePickers`, or use the `DateRangePicker` with `calendars={2}`.

Comment: No, I don't want to choose two dates, I just want one date and the reason why I want to do this (two calendar for DatePicker component) is that the next or previous month is in front of the user and has a better choice.

Comment: Interesting. I'd guess there is no way to do that using only one DatePicker, so maybe you can hack your way into that with several DatePickers managed by a common state. That being said, in terms of UX, the MUI team probably has made a conscious choice of only displaying one month at a time in a non-range DatePicker for a good reason. People are now used to having only one month in their regular DatePickers. Displaying two months in a single picker is commonly reserved for picking a date range. Hope this helps!